# Codeigniter, problem with extended class methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

It’s been a while since I don’t use CI and I’m with a starter doubt.

**EDIT:**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('usuario')) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }

}

class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        Template::set('title', 'Login');
        Template::set('view', 'home');

    }

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('template');

    }
}
```

What happens is that is the user session is invalid, it will load the *login* view but as in my Home controller contructor method is calling the view *home*, its loading both views on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put this in a hook, put it in `MY_Controller` in the `__construct()` method.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Example:

```
// file application/core/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your code here
    }

}
```

Just make sure that you extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller` in the controllers you want to run this code in. If you have to change all of them, so be it.

UPDATE: You could also try a [`post_controller_constructor`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

> **post_controller_constructor**
>
> Called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.

But I would still prefer the MY_Controller method, as it is more flexible.

Comment: The problem is that User_Controller extends MY_Controller, so it will be on a infinite loop

Comment: Then put it in the constructor of User_Controller. EDIT: How would that cause an infinite loop? It should work fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want *every* request to force a login except the actual login page, or do you want it only for certain controllers?

Comment: yes, check the session for each controller request, isn't that correct?

Comment: It depends on what you want to happen. BTW you need to `exit` when you load the login view, or preferably redirect to a login controller that doesn't extend the one where you do the session check.

Comment: @WesleyMurch let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1028/discussion-between-gerep-and-wesley-murch)